# How to draw a warped text in libgdx?

Tags: java, libgdx

How to draw warped text like this picture in libgdx?

[image: 50.000 and still counting]

Answer (score 1):

There are different methods to do this – and they do not come standard in libgdx, so you will have to implement one yourself.

1. Convert the text to outlines. Warp each of the coordinates. Draw polyfilled objects using these warped coordinates. This is what professional software such as Adobe Illustrator and CorelDraw do.
2. Draw the text into a bitmap. Warp the bitmap. For a better result, draw the bitmap at twice the output size so you can use subsampling.
3. (Based on the rather poor quality of the sample image) Draw each of the characters slightly rotated. You can base the amount of rotation on the total number of characters (quick, dirty, and simple), or ever so slightly improve it by using the individual widths of each character to determine its relative position inside the entire string, and base the amount of rotation on that.

Comment: Do you have any reference link to each method?

Answer (score -1):

Are you going to use this picture for some motion or you just need it for display? If it's the latter why don't you just draw it in gimp, photoshop or even paint and position it/scale it on where you need it on the screen as normal sprite/actor?

Comment: I need it for dynamic content